# Is there a way to move installed apps from one device to another?

Tags: applications

I have Galaxy Tab 7 inch which has some installed apps and I don't have the APK files. I would like to move the apps to a new Galaxy Tab Plus 7 inch.

Is there a way to move my installed apps from one device to another without reinstalling every app from Android Market?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use an app like [ApkBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup) to get the apks of your installed apps than install them on your new device.

Note that the data will be lost and depending on the market version it may not notify you about updates.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Someone suggested backing up my apps to my Market account and installing it into the new Galaxy Tab. Is this possible?

Comment: If you downloaded them from there than they're linked to your account so in the newest version (now called play store) it lists all the apps you ever downloaded. But you'd have to download them one by one. Or if you enabled it there's an option in system settings to backup your list of apps and reinstall them when you set up your new device, but not all of them support this.

Comment: Interesting! I tried this out, but some apps are "protected" and an apk cannot be created. What to do then?