# How to move apps from old Nexus7 to the new one? (multi users)

Tags: backup, restore, titanium-backup, multi-user

I bought a new Nexus7 and now I'd like to move a few games from my old Nexus7 to the new one. On the old and new device I have two users. (if it matters anything)

I tried a few ways...at first I tried TitaniumBackup, but when I move my backup to the new one and check the integrity, titanium backup says that there are faults. When I try the restore, the app hangs at 0%.

Then I tried the adb backup with the Nexus Root Toolkit...but when I restore, the restore windows ever appears at the first user even though I'm logged in at the second user.

Then I thought about, I can do it manually..
I know that the main app data will be saved at /data/data/package and the specific user data will be saved at /data/user/0 or 10 etc /package. I tries to copy the files from one device to the other...but when I start the 
app after the copy process, the app crashs.

So can anyone please help me?

PS: Google Backup Service did only work for a few apps.

Comment: To be clear: is it the game's saved data you want to move, rather than the game itself?

Comment: Related: [Android Apps from Old Tablet to New Tablet](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38872/16575) / [Is there a way to move installed apps from one device to another?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20980/16575) / [Questions about phone migration using rsync](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26131/16575) / [How to migrate applications to other user account without downloading the applications again?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33798/16575)

Comment: I wanted to move the games saved data (the free and bought  apps are still available in the play maket).

I looked at the linked forum posts..but all suggestions uses adb backup/restore (or apps like carbon, which uses adb backup/restore), but adb backup/restore does only work for the device administrator.